# SonarQube upgrade with from 5.6 to 6.3 with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

We are using SonarQube v5.6 with SQL Server 2008 version, and now planning to migrate it to SonarQube 6.3, when I looked at website it says that it supports only SQL Server 2012 + versions.

I work for a big enterprise and it's difficult to get new servers easily. So I want to know that if v6.3 will also work with SQL Server 2008 or not?

Comment: The earliest supported SQL Server version is 2012. SonarQube would be justified to drop support for unsupported database versions - why support for free databases that aren't supported by their own vendor? Who gets to pay for potential incompatibilities or re-implementation of missing features? Most likely they would provide support for obsolete versions for an additional per-case fee. Besides, 2012 isn't *new* anymore. 2012 came out 5 years ago. And SQL Server 2016 SP1 provides enterprise-level features even in the Express edition

Comment: In other words - contact the company directly, ask for a quote to support 2008 (9 year old DB) and explain to management how you can buy a new, bigger server for the same money

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : I am not asking sonar to support SQL server 2008 , just wanted to check if there are any specific reasons that they stopped supporting older versions , like if they are using newer features of 2012 etc. Even we are planning to migrate to newer versions of SQL in future but not now.

Comment: This is not a programming question. It can only be answered by SonarQube. Besides - 2012 is the *old* version now. SonarQube may well be using such *old* features like `OFFSET .. FETCH` for paging, or ROW_NUMBER and other analytic functions. As for reasons - I already provided several: why target an *obsolete* database version? Why hamper *their* product? Which is to say, why should *they* pay in development time for customers that use obsolete versions?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to upgrade but it does not work as Sonar check for sql sever version before it start upgrade. And if it finds unsupported versions, it will not go ahead with upgrade.